# Is there a way to get matplotlib.path.contains_points to be inclusive of boundary points

Tags: python, matplotlib

We have a hit test use case that wishes to also consider points on the actual boundary of a path. We're using matplotlib.path.contains_points to test a bunch of points en masse and it's working very well for us. Today I discovered it returns false for points on the boundary, in our case the origin (0,0) which is a point on the path.

Is there a way to configure the function call to yield `True` on boundary points, that is to be inclusive of the boundary? I'm only seeing it support an exclusive test, but according to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html) there's the other parameters for transform and radius, maybe they have some magic number for pushing the thing to true for boundary points?

> `contains_points(points, transform=None, radius=0.0)` Returns a `bool`
>   array which is `True` if the path contains the corresponding point.
>
> If `transform` is not `None`, the path will be transformed before
>   performing the test.
>
> `radius` allows the path to be made slightly larger or smaller.

Comment: A quick scan of the source code says no. For an operation such as this one, may I suggest using 
[`shapely`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.intersects), which is built specifically for this sort of thing, instead? If you use `shapely` you can take advantage of [`object.intersects`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.intersects) to handle this.

Comment: I'm absolutely open to reimplementing with such a thing. Good to know a general purpose computational geometry library exists. I'm basically doing some Allowable Total Error work you often find with FDA regulations. If shapely can roll with Python 3.6 and reasonably loaded from some Pandas.Series objects directly or via some intermediates I should be good to go. Thanks for sharing. I was going to dig into the source myself later tomorrow, if your quick scan is accurate go ahead and push an answer and I'll check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick scan of the source code says no. `matplotlib` isn't really intended for spatial ops; it just has a little bit of support for them just because it's an old codebase with a huge API surface.

I suggest using 
[`shapely`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.intersects), which is built specifically for spatial operations like this one, instead. If you use `shapely` you can take advantage of [`object.intersects`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.intersects) to handle this.

You can roll your points into a `pandas.Series` consisting of `shapely.Point` objects and your polygons (given a sequence of coordinates) into a `poly = shapely.Polygon(coordinates)` object. Then do something like `points_that_intersect = points[points.map(lambda p: poly.intersects(p)]`